# jQuery Dialog Doesn't Open After Closing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

The below code enables me to open a dialog using content from another page. I then close it. I then try to open it up again and I get this in FireFox

> Error: TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

... and this in Chrome

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Can anyone please help?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            position: 'center',
            title: 'Alternative',
            draggable: false,
            width: 1024,
            height: 768,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true

        });

        $("#dialog_trigger").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").load('index2.html', function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        })

    });
</script>
```

My JS is as follows:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The "close" icon was missing but I moved the bootstrap.js above the UI.js and it came back! If I remove the `load` function so the dialog just opens then it works fine

Thanks

Comment: whats the content of your index2.html? 
what element is dialog?

Comment: Just some "normal" HTML. Nothing fancy. <div id="dialog"></div>

Comment: Could you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing this? So far, I'm unable to reproduce the described behavior.

Comment: Solved! I addddddddddd